# Raspberry connected to adhoc and wifi simultaneously

Tags: raspberry-pi, networking

Currently I am working on a project where we have to connect multiple cameras to a Raspberry.

Our idea is to buy multiple Raspberry PIs with a connected camera.

These raspberries connect to a **master** raspberry with an **adhoc** network, the master raspberry is also connected to the internet (**wifi**), so the photos can be uploaded to a remote server.

Is this the best way to do it?

Is it possible to have a raspberry manage an adhoc network and be connected to wifi at the same time?

How would I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use a standard router?

Comment: Could you explain? @LiorBilia

Comment: @Soundwave what kind of ad-hoc network do you intend to build?  "Ad hoc" means "for this" and implies that something is tailored-made for a specific application. 
When used to describe wireless networks it usually implies that there is no central AP or controller, which makes sense in a large decentralised network, but is that really what you need?

Comment: Btw there are probably better places to ask this question, such as https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ and https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user1890202 I am pretty new to networking so my apologies. I don't think I'll need an ad-hoc network. So what my goal is: I have multiple Raspberries with a camera. And they send photos to a master raspberry. This master uploads the photos to a remote server (via the real internet). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The best way to achieve this depends on your situation, and to which extent you can use any pre-existing WiFi(s). If your Pi:s are going to be in range of one AP then I do recommend getting an off-the-shelf router with WiFi specifically for this project, at least for testing and learning.

Comment: I recommend manually assigning IP-addresses to you Pi:s.

Comment: If all the Pis have wifi anyway, why do you need to go via a "master Pi" at all? Doesn't that just add an unneccesary step to the process?

Comment: @Dampmaskin Right, I was not clear about it. The project will be used in various contexts. One of them where the master PI will be using a cell network. That's why we would like to send all the data to the master.

Comment: @user1890202 this is a superuser question at best, not network engineering nor is it RPI specific.

Answer (score 1):

The best architecture is to use your master 'Pi as a WiFi router.
There are many software options for this ...[here is one](https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/).
Avoid the use of Ad-Hoc networking if you can.

The advantage here is that you can implement at least basic security and provide dynamic IP addresses (you don't want to manage fixed IP addresses if you can avoid it) to all your camera 'Pi's.

Your master 'Pi can then pre-process and forward your data to the Internet via whatever networks you have.

You can plug two WiFi adapters into your master 'Pi to enable it to connect as a client to other WiFi networks. Note however that most WiFi stacks will not allow you to connect to two SSID's simultaneously. It is possible to promiscuously connect to multiple networks, but this is somewhat complex in implementation, so I'd advise against it.